# Convert a List of dict to single dict and it's key and value

Tags: python, django

```
data = [{ "January": {"China": 6569.4, "Japan": 49448.61,"Norway": 28000.0,"Poland": 3525.427,"Singapore": 33190.231851,"United States": 25976.4,"Taiwan": 15363.884885}},
{"February": {"Japan": 2540.32,"Poland": 14750.0,"Singapore": 16044.473973}}]
```

### Expecting Result

```
data = [{ "January": {"China": 6569.4, "Japan": 49448.61,"Norway": 28000.0,"Poland": 3525.427,"Singapore": 33190.231851,"United States": 25976.4,"Taiwan": 15363.884885},
"February": {"Japan": 2540.32,"Poland": 14750.0,"Singapore": 16044.473973}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Please provide the code you tried before asking the question.

```
prepared_dict = {}

for i in data:
    key = list(i.keys())[0]
    value = list(i.values())[0]
    prepared_dict[key] = value
```